# There is an element with order $p$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $p$ is an odd prime and $G$ is a group which has $2p$ elements. Show that there exists at least one element with order $p$.

I tried showing in 2 parts as $G$ is cyclic and not cyclic, but I couldn’t show it for not cyclic groups. I think I must do something different. Could you please help me in the easiest way becasue we have learnt only elemantry theorems and definitions?

Comment: [This is Cauchy's Theorem.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory))

Comment: @Shaun I don’t know that theorem

Comment: Not to worry: the article linked to contains two proofs.

Comment: You probably won't get a suitable answer unless you declare "where you are" in group theory.  Are you in a basic starter course or something more advanced?

Comment: @Shaun I haven’t realized the link thanks I will check on

Comment: @Randall As I said in question, it’s a basic starter course. I know only elemantary theorems and defs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let, $p$ be an odd prime number and $G$ be a group of order $2p$. Then [$G$ has a subgroup of order $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360152/any-group-of-order-2p-has-a-subgroup-of-order-pp-being-a-prime), which is indeed cyclic! Consequently, the subgroup contains an element of order $p$ and so does the group $G$.

Comment: Why is it cyclic?

Comment: (Sub)groups of prime order must be cyclic by Lagrange's theorem.  Do you have access to that theorem?  (I can't see how to do this problem without it.)

Comment: @Randall I have understood, your answer is really helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: I agree with Randall. Groups/Subgroups of prime order are cyclic.

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya thanks I accepted your answer :)